# why CSRF token is not found in Set-Cookie header field?

Tags: python, django, csrf-token

I have a Django Rest-framework APIView class which is as below:

```
class HelloView(APIView):

    def get(self, request):
        clients = client.objects.all()
        serializer = ClientSerializerAPIView(clients, many=True) 
        return Response(serializer.data)
    def post(self, request):
        serializer = ClientSerializerAPIView(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid():
            serializer.save()
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED)
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND)
```

when i send a get request by postman there is a csrf token in the cookie section of postman, but the problem is that there is no Set-Cookie field in the header file received for me to gram csrftoken from.

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is in cookies not in the header you should send in `X-CSRFToken` key in header.

You have to decorate your view with `ensure_csrf_cookie`:

```
from django.views.decorators.csrf import ensure_csrf_cookie
from django.utils.decorators import method_decorator


@method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie, name='dispatch')
class MyView(APIView):
    ...
```

You can also send valid csrf token in response got by `django.middleware.csrf.get_token(request)` 
and set it accordingly.

Comment: thank you for the response. but the cookie should be in Set-Cookie in header. this is a post response i am getting from the server, not a post request. so i can't set X_CSRFToken in post response

Comment: try using `@ensure_csrf_cookie` decorator for your view

Comment: i didn't work with that. but it worked with @method_decorator(ensure_csrf_cookie). thank you very much